How to add module jackson-datatype-jsr310 in Keycloak?
I made a custom SPI for Keycloak(that is running in a docker container, https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/keycloak) and implemented the RealmResourceProvider interface. I wrote a custom endpoint and the Response object that I return contains a LocalDateTime field. I compiled the code and then copied the jar into the keycloak providers folder into my docker container. When calling the endpoint I get a 500 response.
Here is the cusom endpoint:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomOtpProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

private final KeycloakSession keycloakSession;
    
      @POST
      @NoCache
      @Path("/users/{username}/endpoint")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Response endpoint(
              @PathParam("username") final String username, SomeRequestBody someRequestBody) {
    ...
        return Response.ok(new SomeResponse("Some field", LocalDateTime.now())).build();
      }
    }

and the factory:
public class CustomOtpProviderFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

  private static final String PROVIDER_ID = "custom-otps";

  @Override
  public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
    return new CustomOtpProvider(keycloakSession);
  }

and of course I added the factories full classname to the /src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory file
The endpoint worked fine before adding the LocalDateTime field. After adding the field I get this error:
ERROR [io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.mappers.NativeInvalidDefinitionExceptionMapper] (executor-thread-1) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.b.keycloak.model.SomeResponse["expiresAt"])

How do I add the required module in Keycloak?

I see that someone voted to close the question. Plase do not close this question. To everyone who knows Keycloack the question contains enough details. The issue is easy to reproduce. All you need to do is create a custom endpoint in KC and return an object with a LocalDateTime field. That is all there is too it. No further details needed!

I did not vote to close this question, but you should be the one providing debugging details. This is part of StackOverflow's guidelines on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you cannot just say "it's easy to reproduce, just do this". Provide a minimal reproducible example. Don't just paste an error message.

ok. Thanks. I will add details.

@dani-vta details added.
